# Migrating from apollo client:codegen to graphql-codegen

Tags: typescript, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-codegen

I am trying to migrate from `apollo client:codegen --target=typescript --outputFlat
Which generated a type like

```
export interface GetTeamStuffFields_getTeamStuffFields_fields {
  __typename: "TeamStuffField";
  name: string;
  label: string;
  options: GetTeamStuff_getTeamStuffFields_fields_options[] | null;
}
```

Using `graphql-codegen` it changes completely and generates the type like

```
export type GetTeamStuffQuery = {
  readonly getTeamStuffFields: ReadonlyArray<{
    readonly __typename: "TeamStuffSection";
    readonly name: string;
    readonly label: string;
    fields: ReadonlyArray<{
      readonly __typename: "TeamStuffField";
      readonly name: string;
      readonly label: string;
      readonly fieldType: TeamStuffType | null;
      readonly options: ReadonlyArray<{
        readonly __typename: "TeamStuffOption";
        readonly value: string;
        readonly label: string;
      }>;
    }>;
  }>;
};
```

Which would mean I need to migrate all the references, this issue is that we have 100s of these so we would rather get the generator to generate the types how they were before, Is this still possible?

I have tried changing the codegen file with no luck of generating anything similar to what we had.
Types with underscores